# Trigger fargate when new item comes to queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-sqs, aws-fargate, amazon-ecr

Is there a way to trigger a `fargate task`  when a new item comes to the SQS queue. like  lambda trigger.

Comment: This was discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66388494/is-it-possible-to-trigger-an-aws-fargate-task-upon-an-item-being-added-to-an-sqs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to trigger an AWS Fargate task upon an item being added to an SQS queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66388494/is-it-possible-to-trigger-an-aws-fargate-task-upon-an-item-being-added-to-an-sqs)