# Getting metadata from the resource triggering AWS cloudwatch event rule to the target

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an ECS task that processes the data and stores it in the S3 bucket between two dates specified by the user. The design is such that the name of the schedule rule which is "Schedule rule name" is a string that has information about the dates between which we are processing the data.

I want to trigger another ECS task in the same ECS cluster, but different task definition, after the first task (processing and storing the data in S3 between date ranges) is finished. For the next task, I am further processing the data between those two dates specified in the previous task. The two dates are defined as environment variables in my next task.

I would like to know how to pass the details of the previous task, or the trigger, specifically "Schedule rule name" in my case to the next task so that I can get the two dates from the name and pass it as an environment variable to the next task.

Comment: Check out Shitij Matur's answer; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66388494/is-it-possible-to-trigger-an-aws-fargate-task-upon-an-item-being-added-to-an-sqs